# Compiling C++ with SWIG on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, g++, shared-libraries, swig

I am trying to compile a C++ extension using Swig for Mac OS X.  I have run into a few linker errors though.  The basic tutorial for Python Swig also seems to fail on Mac:

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn10

```
swig -c++ -python example.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c example.cxx
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.6
g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

The first three lines work fine.  The last line fails with a linker error.  I tried the last line on OS X with this, and got the same error:

```
g++ -dynamiclib example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

The error from the last line is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyArg_ParseTuple", referenced from:
      __wrap_fact in example_wrap.o
  "_PyArg_UnpackTuple", referenced from:
      _SwigPyObject_own in example_wrap.o
  "_PyBool_FromLong", referenced from:
      _SwigPyObject_richcompare in example_wrap.o
      _SwigPyObject_own in example_wrap.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks.

Comment: `-lpython` at the end of the compile line should address the linking issue, but Mac shared objects have the extension `.dylib`

Comment: Thanks, @Petesh -- that works!  I was getting hung up on a different issue with my main Swig code (undefined symbols for some functions, which I commented out in the swig.i file).  Basic Swig functionality works now.

Comment: Aaaaand again the close-useful-thread fairys strike. This is a common and broad problem working with multiple SWIG based libraries when on a mac. Why the hell would you close it?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For completeness -- thanks Petesh.

```
swig -c++ -python example.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c example.cxx
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.6
g++ -lpython -dynamiclib example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

Comment: There's a typo for those pasting this code: "dynamclib" ---> "dynamiclib"

Comment: I get `ld: library not found for -lpython` for the last line.